# Generated class consumed by another Annotation Processor

Tags: java, android, data-binding, annotations

I'm writing an annotation processor that generates [Android Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)
 [Observable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) objects. The idea is to provide a compatibility shim between the [Realm](https://realm.io/) and databinding libraries.

Sample Output:

```
public class ObservablePerson extends BaseObservable {
    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return getValue(BR.name);
    }

    @Bindable
    public void setName(String name) {
        setValue(BR.name, name);
    }
}
```

The problem is the databinding annotation processor does not process the classes generated by my annotation processor (causing `BR.name` to be unavailable).

I had hoped that the databinding annotation processor would pick up the newly generated classes in a later round, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was doing a few things wrong:

1. My annotation that I was trying to process was referencing the BR.class, which caused the processing of my annotated classes from being processed until after BR.class was generated. This was causing my annotation processor to run in the round after the android databinding processor.
2. The android databinding processor only collects the values for BR.class in the first round. Any files generated in subsequent rounds are ignored. This means that even though the databinding annotation processor was running after my files were generated, the BR class wasn't being updated.
3. The android databinding processor runs in the first round. This effectively precludes consuming classes that are generated by other annotation processors. See (2)

My solution is to build a gradle plugin that will generate an interface containing the `@Bindable` annotations. These files are generated before the compiler runs, guaranteeing they are present for the first round of annotation processing. At that point my annotation processor can generate the files as described above.